# How can create one function from two functions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function, parameters

I would like to create another function in PostgreSQL, function_c, from function_a and function_b.

function_a

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_a(year_ INTEGER, col_b INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
DECLARE 
    vbl INTEGER;
BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT(col_b) INTO vbl
    FROM table1
    WHERE date_part('year',table1.col_aa) = year_ AND table1.col_bb = col_b;
    RETURN vbl; 
END;
$$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

function_b

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_b(year_ INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
DECLARE 
    vbl_b integer;
BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT(col_aa) INTO vble_b
    FROM table1
    WHERE date_part('year',table1.col_aa) = year_;
    RETURN vbl_b
END;
$$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to create function c that including function a and b, returns:
year: year_ parameter of function_b
median: vbl of function_a divided vbl_b of function_b

How can create one function from two functions in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Your question is not having enough details of your problem/query. Please elaborate your problem with some sample data or sample code. otherwise it will attract downvotes / closed

Comment: What do you mean by "relate them"?  If you want to call `function_a` and `function_b` from `function_c`, then you do that, exactly like you would with normal Postgres functions.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly below mentioned definition will work for you

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_c(year_ INTEGER, col_b INTEGER)
RETURNS table (year1 integer, median numeric) AS
$$
DECLARE 
    var1 INTEGER;
    var2 INTEGER;
    var3 numeric;
BEGIN 
var1=(select * from function_a(year_));
var2=(select * from function_b(year_, vol_b));
var3=var1/var2;

return query
select year_, var3;

END;
$$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: It's perfect, but I want the function c without parameters. How can I get it?

Comment: If you will not use parameter with function_c then how you will pass the values in your function_a and function_b.